# flash simplebutton inside symbol (movieclip) instance not working

Tags: flash

I have two flash files (say screenOne.fla and gameA.fla).  After importing the main symbol of screenOne.fla into gameA.fla as a movieclip symbol (call it screenOneSymb), the simple buttons in the instance of screenOneSymb do not work.  By "do not work" I mean they have no rollover, not mouse action, nothing. If I go into the edit "screenOneSymb" in gameA.fla and turn on "Control->enable simplebuttons" the buttons will work while in edit "screenOneSymb" but not on the main flash stage.  I've worked around it, but this is driving me crazy. How do I import multi-layered movieclip symbols (with buttons and animations, etc, etc) and get them to work out of the box?

Thanks

Comment: Aaauuuugh. Thinking about duplicating this and putting a bounty on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you laoding screenOne.fla or screenOne.swf?

Then do you specify loaderContext? In order for the loaded swf to be controlled with the gameA you should use the same ApplicationDomain:

```
loader.load(request, new LoaderContext(true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
```